# How do I separate the array value in php because my checkbox field contains different values?

Tags: php

I have created the checkbox as an array. Now I want to separate the checkbox values based on the user selection of checkbox and then I want to show the form.

After using foreach function I got the value like this class1,class6,class8.
If it is class1 I have show the form fields.
If it is class6 I have to show the form fields.

How to separate the checkbox and match the with if condition.

My form:

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class1">class1
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class6">class6
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class8">class8
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class10">class10
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class12">class12
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="engineering">engineering
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="technology">technology
            </td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My PHP values:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name    = $_POST['txt'];
    $pass    = $_POST['pass'];
    $product = $_POST['chk'];

    //print_r($product);

    foreach ($product as $result => $v)
    {
        echo "The item has" . $v . "<br/>";
    }

}
?>
```

```
if($v=="class1" ||   $v=="class6"  ||  $v=="class8" ||  $v=="class10")
{
?>
<p>class1 subject form</p>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</form>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if($v=="class10" ||   $v=="class12" )
{
?>
<p>class12 subject form</p>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="phyiscs">phyiscs
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</form>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
Here is my class1 form
<p>class1 subject form</p>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</form>
</p>
```

I hope every one understand my question

Comment: Want to make sure I understand, you want different forms to show based on the users input?

Comment: yes I have implemented can you please cross  check this.I have updated in my question.still class1 to class 10 the form is same

Comment: for my db structure class1 to class 8 contains ten fields and  class engineering contains 15 fields shall I want to maintain with different table  in my db or I should use one table alone but I am sure form has different fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are checking the value of `$v` outside the `foreach` loop, which does not make sense -- `$v` is just *one* of the possibly many values in the array, so you can't use it to draw conclusions safely.

You could test with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead:

```
if (in_array("class1", $product) || in_array("class6", $product) || ... ) {
    // show some elements
}
```

Of course that gets cumbersome if you want to check for a lot of possibilities. In that case you could use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and introduce some variables for readability:

```
$class1SubjectFormValues = ['class1', 'class6', 'class8', ... ];
$class12SubjectFormValues = ['class10', 'class12', 'class8', ... ];

if (array_intersect($product, $class1SubjectFormValues)) {
    // class1 subject form
}
if (array_intersect($product, $class12SubjectFormValues)) {
    // class12 subject form
}
```

Comment: @mathewjohn sorry, I didn't quite understand this question.

Comment: sorry . I have another problem here if it is class1 the form fields are different, class6 I have show form fields. some time user choose class1 and class6  at the time I want to show both the form?any solution for this

Comment: If user select class1 I have list the class1 form?
If User select class6 I have to combine class1 and class6 under one form.
Like wise user select class1,class6,engg. I want to make all the form elments under one form. How to do thid